# Xcode Unable to install "Runner" : Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, xcode14

I am trying to run an old project from Xcode again but it is not installing even though I it build successfully. I didn't change a single line of code. I am using Flutter in this project but it not even running in Xcode.

I am trying to run it on an iPhone 13 Pro with iOS 16.5.1

Deleting the app from my device completely and reinstalling it does not help.

[image]

Details:

```
Details

Unable to install "Runner"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
Recovery Suggestion: Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-07-13 15:36:34 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
There was an internal API error.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000067)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000121e704c0 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 235
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000121eacc96 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010643cd7a DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000121eac9bb -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1409
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000112ed273a __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.301 + 3540
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001065725ce __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x00000001065730e2 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 196
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80b4047fb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80b405a44 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80b40bac4 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 694
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80b40c5b4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff80b416ad7 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 762
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80b581ce3 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff80b580c67 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,2";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.5.1 (20F75)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 7281;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402653081";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos16.4";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.4";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.0 (Build 22A380)
Xcode 14.3.1 (21815) (Build 14E300c)
Timestamp: 2023-07-13T18:36:34+03:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I ran the app on the simulator instead of my iPhone I could figure out more details. For my other app target "OneSignalExtension" there were not placeholder attributes set. That means the version number and build number were empty and there was no value there thus the app could not be installed on the device.

When I fixed this manually it worked flawlessly then.

Comment: Hello, by version/build numbers, are you referring to ios/runner/info.plist file?

Comment: @themag Thats regarding the main project but we need to get all its targets. When you open xcode and tap your project and all its target you can set all build and version numbers

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a version of the app from the App Store installed. Removing the app-store version allowed me to install my development build from my Xcode